# Proving finite group is commutative if there are representatives of its conjugacy classes that commute pairwise

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Aluffi IV.1.11 suggests proving that if a group $G$ is finite and there exist $g_1, \dots, g_r$ — representatives of all the $r$ conjugacy classes such that they commute pairwise, then the group is commutative. He also gives a hint to think about the sizes of the classes.

Working backwards, $G$ is commutative if $Z(G) = G$, that is, if each conjugacy class is trivial, that is, its size is $1$ and $[g_i] = \{ g_i \}$. But how do I prove this?

I know this problem is [solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438933/finite-group-is-abelian-if-the-representatives-of-its-conjugacy-classes-commute) by resorting to the fact that for any $H$ a proper subgroup of $G$, $G$ is never the union of conjugates of $H$, but this fact is given as an exercise that follows this one, so I guess the author intended a different proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $G$ is the trivial group, we are done. Let $|G|=n$. If $r=n$, we are done. Suppose $r<n$. Without loss of generality, let $g_{1}$ be the identity element. For $i\geq 2$, $|[g_{i}]|=|G:C_{G}(g_{i})|$. Since $g_{i}$ commutes with all $g_{j}$'s, $|C_{G}(g_{i})|\geq r$. So $|[g_{i}]|=n/|C_{G}(g_{i})|\leq n/r$. Then 
$$
n=|G|=|[g_{1}]|+\sum_{i=2}^{r}|[g_{i}]|
\leq 1+\frac{n}{r}(r-1)
=1+n-\frac{n}{r}. 
$$
So $n\leq r$, contradiction.

Comment: That's a beautiful proof, way better than an inductive abomination with a bunch of cases I tried to build myself, thanks!

Comment: Thanks. That hint is helpful.

Comment: Hi! I'm wondering if anyone could help clarify the notation for me: Is $[g_1]$ the conjugacy class of $g_1$ or $Z(G)$?

Comment: @cheeseboardqueen $[g_{1}]$ is the conjugacy class of $g_{1}$.